# ReplicaSet Member Level Access Control

Tags: mongodb, database-administration

Is there any way we can restrict a user to read only from secondary?

Note: I already know about **readPreference**, but in this method its upto the person whether he uses **Secondary** or **Primary**. We as a **DBA** can't restrict him.

Comment: In principle you could permit connection only to secondary. But this would be based on client IP rather than the user name. And of course, it would become a problem when another primary is elected.

Comment: Thanks @WernfriedDomscheit for attention! Is there any way we can restrict SecondaryPrefered on User Priviledge Level or on Server level. Like if any of the secondaries are up a user must read from the secondaries.

Comment: Or we can create ReplicaSet Member Specific Users that wouldn't authenticate on other members

Comment: I don't think that's possible, because users (include local users) are also replicated from primary to secondary.

Answer (score 1):

Access control applies to the object that is being operated on (database, collection, etc.) not to the state of the server (primary/secondary).

You could set up a dedicated analytics node (with priority=0) and firewall rules to permit a set of users access to this node and prohibit access to transactional servers which may become primaries, but I don't see how to achieve this with users/roles.

Comment: Thanks for you response. For Priority = 0 Nodes firewall method would work but How would we achieve this in 3 Member ReplicaSet 1 P 2 S. We need to restrict reading from current Primary.